# Защищаем куки

Tags: php, cookie

Как лучше и через какие фильтры, как шифровать куки, храня в них пароль, у меня есть при входе функция запоминания пользователя вот ведь мне же нужно записывать его данные т.е Логин пароль...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не храните в куках никакой личной информации. Все, что шифруется, может быть дешифровано, потому что где-то должны храниться ключи дешифрации. Если и нужно преобразование в нечитаемую глазу ересь, то это "шифрование" должно быть односторонним, без расшифрования, т.е. - хэшированием.

Вместо того, чтобы каждый раз авторизовывать пользователя (сравнивать пароль и логин), можно авторизовать один раз и *запомнить авторизацию*, при этом передаваться должен минимум сведений о клиенте. В PHP существует система [сессий](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php) - хранилищ для пользователя, которая существует поверх кук, когда в куку пишется идентификатор хранилища, а в самом хранилище валяется что угодно - хоть логин, хоть пароль, хоть флаг "пользователь авторизован" (хранилище, понятное дело, расположено на сервере). Так можно решить первую проблему - избежать сохранения логина и пароля в куках, однако сама проблема украденных кук остается. Эта проблема решается за счет хэширования: берется набор уникальных данных о пользователе (айпи, порт**(!)**, строка юзер-агента браузера, айди) и хэшируется каким-нибудь md5, после чего этот хеш записывается в сессию. При каждом обращении пользователя к сайту хэш регенерируется, и, если он не совпадает с тем, что в сессии, пользователь **не авторизуется** движком.

Сам механизм сессий встроен в PHP, и одна сессия для пользователя будет существовать до закрытия браузера, но некоторые параметры (если не все) могут быть настроены через соответствующие [функции](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) и php.ini, в крайнем случае это все довольно легко переписывается для БД.

Comment: Сгласен, в сессионных переменных намного безопаснее держать данные. Но тут есть один неприятный момент. Сессии - нестабильная штука. Она вроде бы закрывается после закрытия браузера (по умолчанию) или по истечению определенного времени (можно задать вручную). Но может на хостинге быть какой-то сбой или глюк и сессия досрочно закрывается и пользователя выбрасывает в самый неподходящий момент.

Comment: @mountpoint вы куки с сессиями путаете (про закрытие браузера)

Comment: @eicto, эм, я как бы о сессиях говорил =) или мы друг друга не поняли))

Comment: @mountpoint, если сервак ребутнуть, то да, слетят. Но в этом случае обычно пинать (менять) хостера надо.

Comment: @mountpoint, @Fike или просто самому контролировать сессии.. http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-set-save-handler.php

@mountpoint, ещё раз повторяю - от закрытия браузера могут зависеть только куки.

Comment: @eicto, 

> от закрытия браузера могут зависеть только куки

вы имеете ввиду, что при закрытии браузера удаляется кука, которая содержит идентификатор сессии, следовательно удаляется и сессионное хранилище?

Comment: @mountpoint, да, потому что оно сдохнет через какое-то время, потому что некому больше будет его запрашивать.

Comment: хранилище не удаляется, невостребованная сессия лежит спокойно до наступления [session.gc-maxlifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) после чего её **может** собрать сборщик мусора.